# Trying to understand the code in this implementation of strtok

Tags: c, strtok

I am very much a **c** newbie and I am learning by following CS107 videos from Standford (I am not a Student there).

Links are below if anyone is interested

Looking at the below implementation of `strtok`, I am not sure why the first **if** statement is written this way: `if (s == NULL && ((s = p) == NULL))`

```
char *strtok(char *s, const char *sep)
{
    static char *p = NULL;

    if (s == NULL && ((s = p) == NULL))
        return NULL;
    s += strspn(s, sep);
    if (!*s)
        return p = NULL;
    p = s + strcspn(s, sep);
    if (*p)
        *p++ = '\0';
    else 
        p = NULL;
    return s;
}
```

Here's what I have identified so far:

> 1) the static `p` is a local static so that it persists once a token
>   is found, and reset to NULL when no more are found
>
> 2) subsequent calls of `strtoken` pass in `s` as `NULL`

Therefore wouldn't the first check be the same if it were written as:

```
if (s == NULL && p == NULL)
```

Or is there a reason it is written the way it is?

Finally: `return p = NULL`; is this just a shorthand for:

```
p = NULL;
return p;
```

[CS107 Winter 18 Screencasts](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs107/syllabus.html)

[Amazing CS107 Lectures from 2011](https://see.stanford.edu/Course/CS107/198)

[An Rpi based CS107e](http://cs107e.github.io/)

Comment: If you're just learning C try and stay away from doing assignments inside of `if` conditions.

Comment: I agree, I have good `python` experience and I have not seen or used that very much in `python` -- which is why it was intimidating when I first read this implementation.

Comment: This is some unusually ugly code even by C standards, so the author of this code was certainly not aiming for clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (s == NULL && ((s = p) == NULL))
```

is not really the same as

```
if (s == NULL && p == NULL)
```

although they have the same result, when `s` and `p` are `NULL`.

You've identified correctly that subsequent calls of `strtok` must be passed
with `NULL`, however if the are still tokens to be returned, `p` is not going
to test for `NULL`.

So the `((s = p) == NULL)` is a clever trick to assign `s` to point to the
rest of the string where more token might be found.

In C when you evaluate an expression like `A && B`, `A` gets evaluated and `B`
gets only evaluated if and only if `A` was evaluated as true, the reason for
this are [sequent points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point).

If `s` is not `NULL`, then `((s = p) == NULL)` is never evaluated, `s = p` is
never assigned.

If `s` is `NULL`, then  `((s = p) == NULL)` gets evaluated. First `s = p` is
evaluated and this is an assignment. If `p` is not `NULL`, then `s` points to
where `p` is pointing (the rest of the source) and when compared to `NULL`, it
is evaluated to false, thus the `return NULL` is not executed and the function
continues looking for tokens.

If however `p` is also `NULL`, `s` is set to point to `NULL` and when compared
to `NULL` it evaluates to true, the whole `if` evaluates to true and `return NULL` is executed. When `s` initially is `NULL` and `p` is `NULL`, then that
means that all token have been found and return, so the function should return
`NULL`. It can be rewritten as:

```
if(s == NULL)
{
    if(p == NULL)
        return NULL;

    s = p;
}
...
```

Note that the value of an assignment is the value of the assigment itself.

```
return a = b;
```

is the same as doing

```
a = b;
return b;
```

Comment: Great answer! Here's what I have now:
On the first call `s += strspn(s, sep); `: the `s` pointer will move by `1` if `sep` is found. Then `p = s + strcspn(s, sep);` will set `p` to just after the separator in `s`. 
So second call `p` is not null.  But in second call `s` is set to `p` which was set in the previous call.  So `s += strspn(s, sep); `  is really `p += strspn(p, sep); ` because as you said, `s=p` happens during the second call when `s` is ` NULL`;

Answer (score 1):

> Therefore wouldn't the first check be the same if it were written as:

```
if (s == NULL && p == NULL)
```

When `p` is NULL, yes. When `p` is not NULL, no. Because then the side effect of `s=p` doesn't happen. And this value `s` is used later when the `if` statement is false.

> Finally: return p = NULL; is this just a shorthand for:

```
p = NULL;
return p;
```

Yes.

Comment: This is a good answer, but the explanation above is excellent!